# ways to execute python

Tags: python

So far to execute a Python program, I'm using

```
> python file.py
```

I want to run the Python script simply using file name, like

```
> file.py
```

similar to shell scripts like

```
> sh file.sh
> chmod +x file.sh
> ./file.sh
```

or move file.sh to bin and then run

```
> file.sh
```

Comment: thanks guyz ..it's clear now .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put this at the top of your Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

The #! part is called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), and the `env` command will simply locate `python` on your `$PATH` and execute the script through it.  You could hard-code the path to the python interpreter, too, but calling `/usr/bin/env` is a little more flexible.  (For instance, if you're using virtualenv, that python interpreter will be found on your `$PATH`.)

Comment: You can also target specific versions with "#! /usr/bin/env python2.6" or "#! /usr/bin/env python3.0" which might be a good idea given the 2.6+ and 3.0+ split.

Answer (score 2):

You ca also target the specific location of the python interpreter you wan to use, if you need to specify it (e.g, you're using different versions) Just add to the shebang line (the one starting with #!) the complete path of the interpreter you wan to use, for example

```
#!/home/user/python2.6/bin/python
```

But, in general, is better just to take the default using `/usr/bin/env`, as Mike says, as you don't have to rely on a particular path.